# Ask for template when adding a new page

Tags: pages, hooks

I would ask the admin which template they would like to user when they click on "Add New" Page.

Is this possible? I think I have seen something similar before where it ask you how many columns you would like.

I'm assuming it's a hook.

Does anyone know any resources I can have a look at.

Thanks

---

### EDIT

1. Click on Pages > Add New
2. Modal type window will pop up with the options to select page type (These are just page templates ) eg; Default, Contact, 2 columns, etc
3. Select

Comment: What do you mean by "ask"? In general, please explain your question in more detail. It's unclear what you're asking, let alone what you've tried to solve the problem and what went wrong.

Comment: I've seen templates with a custom value set in post / pages admin screens that adds a custom class name to `<body>` then uses CSS to style the output accordingly.  The template I was looking at gave you a choice of sidebar left or sidebar right (where sidebars were home to widgets...)  Pretty easy to manage as long as you stay within the realm of CSS tools.  Not as fancy as multiple output templates, but MUCH easier to manage.

Comment: @user742736 Please update the question with the relevant codes and with details of what you have tried so far!!